# Advanced controls for Minecraft Bedrock PS4

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

After watching some Minecraft Java Edition videos I realized that there are plenty of controls not implemented, or not explained, in Minecraft Bedrock for PS4.
For example...

###### In the inventory:

[image: tri]: Quickly moves a block/item into its appropriate space, of between inventory and hotbar
[image: square]: Take half of the highlighted stack
[image: square]: Place one item from a stack in a slot
[image: square] (hold and drag): Place one item from a stack in each inventory slot
Double[image: X]: Sort loose highlighted items into one stack

###### From the hotbar:

[image: R2] (R2): Wear/switch highlighted piece of armor from the hotbar

Is there anything useful I'm missing?